# How can I perform different actions based on which browser I'm using?

Tags: ruby, cucumber, watir, watir-webdriver

I'm performing testing with Watir in Chrome Firefox and IE. In both Chrome and Firefox the mouseover event does the trick but in IE I have to use hover. The code works as I've tested it outside of the if statement for all three browsers. I just can't get seem to get this if statement to work properly. Any ideas?

```
if @browser.name == 'firefox' or 'chrome'
  @browser.span(:text => /#{tab_name}/i).parent.fire_event 'mouseover'
else
  @browser.span(:text => /#{tab_name}/i).parent.hover
end
```

`@browser.name` is returning correctly as verified by using `puts`.

Thanks,
Adam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the problem that you are seeing is that it always executes the if part and never the else part. Your problem can be simplified to:

```
browser = 'ie'
if browser == 'firefox' or 'chrome'
  puts 'mouseover'
else
  puts 'hover'
end
#=> "mouseover" (which is not as desired)
```

The problem is that your if statement says that (the browser needs to equal "firefox") OR (the string "chrome" must be truthy). The latter will always be true, which is why you always get the if part executing.

You need to do:

```
browser = 'ie'
if browser == 'firefox' or browser == 'chrome'
  puts 'mouseover'
else
  puts 'hover'
end
#=> "hover" (as desired)
```

It could also be more nicely written as:

```
browser = 'ie'
if ['firefox', 'chrome'].include?(browser)
  puts 'mouseover'
else
  puts 'hover'
end
#=> "hover" (as desired)
```

There is also a second issue - `@browser.name` will never be 'firefox' or 'chrome'. Browser#name returns a symbol rather than a string. For example, with Firefox:

```
require 'watir'
browser = Watir::Browser.new :firefox
puts browser.name.class
#=> Symbol
p browser.name
#=> :firefox
```

You need to be matching `@browser.name` against the respective symbols - `:firefox` and `:chrome`.

So taking these two concepts and going back to your original code, it could be fixed with:

```
if [:firefox, :chrome].include?(@browser.name)
  @browser.span(:text => /#{tab_name}/i).parent.fire_event 'mouseover'
else
  @browser.span(:text => /#{tab_name}/i).parent.hover
end
```

Comment: Thanks very much! Just to be clear though it was executing the else part every time.

Comment: I tried the solution you provided running firefox and it still executed the else block.

Comment: Try the updated answer. The problem is that Browser#name returns a symbol rather than a string.

Comment: I'll give it a try but it looks like it returns a string in the rdoc. [Watir Rdoc for browser.name](http://rubydoc.info/gems/watir-webdriver/Watir/Browser#name-instance_method)

Comment: Yes, I saw that too. The docs will be updated in the next release (see [Issue 231](https://github.com/watir/watir-webdriver/pull/231))

Answer (score 0):

I've come up with a temporary solution. I'm catching the exception the webdriver and rescuing with the other line of code like so:

```
begin
  @browser.span(:text => /#{tab_name}/i).parent.hover
rescue Selenium::WebDriver::Error::InvalidElementStateError
  @browser.span(:text => /#{tab_name}/i).parent.fire_event 'mouseover'
end
```

I'm still not sure why the original code doesn't work though.